# I need Excel VBA code to save as a work book to a non-vba Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

currently I am opening a file, running a bit of code to clear entries, then I want to save the file in a new folder.

```
strFilefullname = ThisWorkbook.FullName
x = InStr(1, strFilefullname, "2019")
NewYear = 2020
newFileFullName = Mid(strFilefullname, 1, x - 1) & NewYear & Mid(strFilefullname, x + 4,len(strFilefullname) - 62)
```

Up to this point it is working good by taking the current file path and name:
`I:\EUG\Eugene Timesheets\Bill's Timesheets\timesheets\2019\5 - May\5 - Bill F - May 1-15 Timesheet.xls`
and converting it to this:
`I:\EUG\Eugene Timesheets\Bill's Timesheets\timesheets\2020\5 - May\5 - Bill F - May 1-15 Timesheet`
(NOTE: stripped off the file extension in this case to help

but when it gets down to this part of the code

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
wb.saveas Filename:=newFileFullName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I get  a Run-time error '1004 . Method 'SaveAs'of object'_workbook'failed.
It is my impression that since I have the 2019 version open I should be able to save it as the 2020 version and keep it macros free by doing this. 
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Side note - instead of using `Mid` and then concatenating the parts, why not just use `Replace`?

Comment: Also - does that folder exist? `...2020\5 - May`?

Comment: Your file format has to match the extension, or it will fail

Comment: @BigBen  yes the folder exist and I didn't know about replace!  I will file that one away, thanks!

Comment: @braX are you saying I need to include the .xlsx extension in the save string like this: 'I:\EUG\Eugene Timesheets\Bill's Timesheets\timesheets\2020\5 - May\5 - Bill F - May 1-15 Timesheet.xlsx'

Comment: Yes, meaning that you cannot save it as an XLS if you use the XLSX file format. It's a pretty simple thing to try to see if I'm right, right?

Comment: @braX  I just tried modifying it and I still get the same error. To be clear I am opening a XLS file - Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet, importing a module, running the module, and in said module it will take the opened workbook and save it in a new folder as a macro free XLSX file

Comment: Honestly, the way I would approach it is by putting the code in an XLAM file, including that in Excel as an Add-In, and then you can open the XLS file and modify it without adding any code to it in the first place.

Comment: running with that, but I forsee the save still being an issue

Comment: If the save is still an issue, either something is wrong with the filename, or the destination folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Trying to do the add-in and it is now thinking that the file name is C:\Users\BillF.VNZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\year.xla  ( i did xla as the files are xls ). So I will shelf the add - in and open a new question for that specifically.

Comment: OMG I am an idiot!!!!  you are correct the folder doesn't exist.    I am pulling from a folder 2019/5-may/ or 2019/6-jun.   I am saving to a folder /2020/    no month path.  the files get moved to the month folders after they are filled out.  as such I have not built the month folders yet   I am so sorry.